# HashMap not updating its values by reference

Tags: java, reference, hashmap

I haven't found nothing that helped me, but if it is already made the question sorry.

This is my problem:

```
String descri = "";

for (int i = 0; i <vDatos.size(); i++) {    
    HashMap tabla = ((HashMap) vDatos.get(i));
    descri = "Hello";
    tabla.put("DESCRIPTION",descri);                    
}
```

tabla is an hashmap made by reference from vDatos, when I put another value (descColumna,Descri) it does not update vDatos value.

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!.

UPDATE: Code symplify

Comment: You've provided an unnecessarily complex example where we don't know what anything is. Please simplify it. Provide an MCVE and explain what you expect to happen (and why) and what actually does.

Comment: You must provide more code. What is the variable columnaTabla? And provide some more explanation. Java HashMap keys are considered to be equal if they are equal by .equals method I'm fairly sure

Comment: And don't use raw types. And follow Java's naming conventions.

Comment: The problem is that after updating tabla, vDatos.get(i) doesn't contain the new value "DESCRIPTION" with its value.

Comment: How do you verify that?

Comment: In debug i look vDatos.get(i) value and it doesn't contain the new value

Comment: With the same value of `i` as the one you used to get the `HashMap` originally?

Comment: Apart from that im running this code in jboss EAP 6.2 and java 7.

Comment: *In debug i look vDatos.get(i) value and it doesn't contain the new value* - you are probably looking at it **after** the *i++* so you are looking at the following value. Try `vDatos.get(i-1)`.

Comment: if you don't provide the code containing the issue we cannot help, add the part where you create `tabla` and `vDatos`

Comment: no I look at the first value  value because vDatos is a vector and i get the first hashmap.

Comment: @Paizo it comes from the EAR, this code is execute has jboss module and vDatos vector is very complex but it contains only hashmaps.

Comment: you are doing something wrong which is not shown in the question; it works for me -- http://ideone.com/GuazGB

Comment: Is it possible that your code overwrites the new value with the old value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems unlikely. Try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i <vDatos.size(); i++) {    
  HashMap tabla = ((HashMap) vDatos.get(i));
  descri = "Hello";
  tabla.put("DESCRIPTION",descri); 
  HashMap foo = ((HashMap) vDatos.get(i));  
  System.out.println(foo.get("DESCRIPTION"));
}
```

I'm pretty sure it would say 'Hello'. Looking at the contents of a HashMap in debug is error-prone and confusing, and easy to miss what you are looking for.

EDIT:WORKED